# Getting property types from a component's default props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to get the prop types of a component's default props i'm selecting (and getting via a ref), in order to make a generic property editor for multiple component types.

The idea would be to be able that some of the properties are actually collections, on which i'll have implement adding or removing children.

An alternative would be to be able to add some kind of metadata, so i know which is the type of each property.

Did anyone do something similar to this or has any idea on an approach?